# Adding two indexed geometries to a BufferGeometry

Tags: javascript, three.js, geometry, webgl

At the moment I'm using a set of predefined data (containing the indices, vertices and colors) and multiple `THREE.Geometry`'s to add objects to a scene. As you could imagine, this is pretty slow as it requires adding and removing many objects at once or merging many together.

However if I used a single `THREE.BufferGeometry` this would allow me to use `_gl.bufferSubData` to add and remove objects and in theory should have minimal affect on the performance.

The trouble I'm having is putting this into practice. I already have the `bufferSubData` function working, however I'm unable to add two sets of data in the same BufferGeometry. I'm guessing this is because the data does not follow on from each other (as they're two separate objects) so they're both using the same indices. [This image shows the result](http://puu.sh/6SpMK.jpg).

I've created a JSFiddle which uses an array named `section` containing the chunk data. If anyone could take a look and change it so it adds both sets of data I would really appreciate it:

http://jsfiddle.net/dUqwT/

Also, I've been unable to find the purpose of the index offset. If someone could link or explain what it's used for, that would be very helpful.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, worked out how it's done and I've updated the JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/dUqwT/1/

It was more simple than I thought and it had nothing to do with the index offset (still no idea what that does). I just ensured that it appends to each array correctly so positions, indices and colors aren't overwritten. Did that by using two variables and setting them to the appropriate lengths.

Realistically, as the objects I'm adding to the BufferGeometry will be dynamic, I'll need to give each object a certain amount of the buffer it can use instead of setting two vars to the length. That will allow me to then remove and change each object using `_gl.bufferSubData`.

```
for (var chunkID = 0; chunkID < 2; chunkID++) {

    var chunkIndices = section[chunkID].indices;
    var chunkVertices = section[chunkID].vertices;
    var chunkColors = section[chunkID].colors;

    var sectionXPos = chunkID * 32;
    var sectionYPos = 0;
    var sectionZPos = 0;

    // Add indices to BufferGeometry
    for ( var i = 0; i < chunkIndices.length; i ++ ) {
        var q = chunkIndices[i];

        var j = i * 3 + iLength;

        indices[ j ]     = (q[0] + vLength / 3) % chunkSize;
        indices[ j + 1 ] = (q[1] + vLength / 3) % chunkSize;
        indices[ j + 2 ] = (q[2] + vLength / 3) % chunkSize;

    }

    // Add vertices to BufferGeometry
    for ( var i = 0; i < chunkVertices.length; i ++ ) {
        var q = chunkVertices[i];

        var j = i * 3 + vLength;

        // positions
        positions[ j ]     = q[0] + sectionXPos;
        positions[ j + 1 ] = q[1] + sectionYPos;
        positions[ j + 2 ] = q[2] + sectionZPos;

        // colors
        var hexColor = chunkColors[i / 4];
        color.set(hexColor);

        colors[ j ]     = color.r;
        colors[ j + 1 ] = color.g;
        colors[ j + 2 ] = color.b;
    }

    iLength += chunkIndices.length * 3;
    vLength += chunkVertices.length * 3;
}
```

Comment: Your fiddles aren't working. Could you update them? I am interested in your question/answer...